# Using Make's 'wildcard' function in Android.mk

Tags: android, c, makefile, android-ndk

I'm having a problem using [Make's `wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Wildcard-Function.html) in my Android.mk build file.

My other makefiles use a line like this one to specify "All .c files in this folder":

`CFILES := $(wildcard *.c)`

In my Android.mk file I tried this:

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard *.c)`

However, this has the same affect as not including any files at all.

If I include the files manually the build works as I'd expect.

I'm wondering if maybe the current working directory isn't my project path at the time this statement is evaluated? If so, can I use a combination of `$(call my-dir)` and the wildcard function to get the list I want?

Comment: Try specifying a `VPATH`

Comment: @BrianCain like so: `VPATH := $(call my-dir)`? That didn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's what I've used in the past for doing this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

'my-dir' is a macro provided by the build system and returns the path of the directory containing the Android.mk file.

Comment: Wow... thank you. That's exactly what I needed. I had written a shell script to generate the .mk dynamically because I was tired of mucking around with it. But this is just what I needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of "this directory" is "the directory containing this makefile", then

```
$(wildcard $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))*.c)
```

ought to work.

(caveat: I don't know from Android)