# Android.mk wilcard extra 'jni' in path?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I try to use wilcards in Android.mk with help of this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459242/1039175 
But get and error:

**make:  No rule to make target `jni/jni/abyss_engine.c', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/AbyssEngine/jni/abyss_engine.o'** - this error means no source file found and it's natural because where no jni subfolder in jni folder

Where comes an extra jni in path and why? My source files just in jni folder without any subfolders, how to fix it?

My Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := AbyssEngine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c)
 (**abyss_engine.c asset_manager.c jni_bridge.c shader_manager.c input_manager.c works fine**) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2 
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All thanks to **a1** from android-ndk group

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES=$(notdir $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c))
```

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/9d4251e0900a31e6/4b792fc207e454c2#4b792fc207e454c2 - there is more useful info in his reply

Comment: The notdir only remove all directory informations from LOCAL_SRC_FILES, but does not avoid ndk to append jni when building.

I only get file "jni/hello.cpp" instead of "jni/../../mydir/hello.cpp" :(

Answer (score 0):

I use External Tools to complie file, and  I met this problem in my project。

I change the Working directory Path and the problem is solved。

step1：
 Settings -> Tools -> External Tools -> NDK ->my build -> Working directory

step2：

my old Working directory path is ：`$ModuleFileDir$\src\main`

I change it to ： `$ModuleFileDir$\src\main\jni`

and It runs very well for me！