# GNU make - finding sources from parent directories with wildcard

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, makefile

I'm re-asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350878/using-makes-wildcard-function-in-android-mk) question, with a twist:

How do I specify the wildcard pattern when the files are in parent directory of LOCAL_PATH?

say, files would be `../../src/foo.cpp` and `../../src/bar.cpp`.

code `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard ../../src/*.cpp)` assigns an empty string.

Comment: If you get an empty string, that means your path is wrong.  What happens when, in the same directory where make is running (remember this might _not_ be the directory the makefile is in!!) you run `ls ../../*.cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, but I'm not quite sure what was the problem.

Old script:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard ../../src/*.cpp)
```

The new script that works:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/..
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard ../src/*.cpp)
```

I guess my-dir and wildcard do not refer to same working directory.

Android ndk toolchain expects to find the make file (android.mk) in `/jni` folder. `$(call my-dir)` seems to return `/jni` directory (because that's where the make file is). However `$(wildcard )` seems to look from the current directory.

I'm not quite sure if I'm right here, but effectively it seems to be so.

EDIT: And here's the working script that I used before this attempt with wildcard
(just to explain you why I initially did what I did)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../src/foo.cpp \
../../src/bar.cpp
```